# How can I get the qualified Git URL of a remote using url.<base>.insteadOf?

Tags: git

I work with a Git repository using the *[url.<base>.insteadOf](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config)* scheme to store the actual repo URL in my ~/.gitconfig.  One of the applications I use tries to figure out the access scheme (ssh, http, etc) to the repo using *git-config* but it fails since the output looks something like this:

```
# git config --get remote.origin.url
gerrithost:department/project
```

Where *gerrithost* is set up in my *~/.gitconfig*:

```
[url "ssh://machine.dn.tld:29418/"]
insteadOf = gerrithost:
```

The application expects the output of *git config --get remote.origin.url* to look like:

```
ssh://machine.dn.tld:29418/department/project
```

*git remote -v* displays the resolved URLs but I would have to parse the output to get the correct remote and field.

Is it possible to get the resolved URL using git-config (or one of the other tools) or do i have to revert to writing a parser for *git remote*?

Comment: I just tested, and I don't see any resolution when trying a `git remote -v` (with git 1.9.1 or 1.9.2). I still see `xxx:repo`. That should mean that, if your app see an url with '`:/`' in it (and no '`://`'), it can assume its url scheme is ssh.

Comment: @VonC Right now it actually checks both the protocol (ssh) and the port (29418) in order to verify that it is a Gerrit URL.  It's not my application and I'm not sure upstream would accept a patch if I remove the port check.  :/

Comment: I understand. I was just surprised you mentioned that `git remote -v` resolved anything: it doesn't on my side.

Comment: I'm using git version 1.9.0, perhaps it is a new feature?

Comment: but I did mention I tested it with git 1.9.1 and 1.9.2: that seems more recent that 1.9.0, doesn't it?

Comment: @VonC Sorry, I had too much coffee today. ^^

Comment: `git ls-remote --get-url` ?

Comment: Creating an answer would be great. At the moment the question appears pretty high in the unanswered list.

Answer (score 1):

As Stefan Näwe already explained in the comments, the command you are looking for is

```
git ls-remote --get-url
```

For more information take a look at the [`ls-remote` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-ls-remote.html).